# While I'm trying to run apache atlas. I'm facing some hbase error(I'm using embedded hbase and solr)

Tags: apache-atlas

My apache atlas server is started but I found errors in my application.log file.

ui for apache atlas is also not running.

1. I've followed each and every step from apache website. All went good.
2. I gave all permissions in atlas-env.sh and application-properties files.
3. can anyone help me to how to figure it out?

```
Running setup per configuration atlas.server.run.setup.on.start. (SetupSteps$SetupRequired:186)
2019-10-25 12:25:49,366 WARN  - [main:] ~ Running setup per configuration atlas.server.run.setup.on.start. (SetupSteps$SetupRequired:186)
2019-10-25 12:25:50,104 WARN  - [main:] ~ Retrieve cluster id failed (ConnectionImplementation:551)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/hbaseid
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionImplementation.java:549)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionImplementation.java:287)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:114)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase2.HBaseCompat2_0.createConnection(HBaseCompat2_0.java:46)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase2.HBaseStoreManager.<init>(HBaseStoreManager.java:314)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:58)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:476)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:408)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseC
```

Answer (score 1):

When HBase starts, HBase Master node creates the node "/hbase/hbaseid" in zookeeper.

## 1. Check the processes.

check HBase and zookeeper are running or not with 'jps -m'.
If you configured HBase manages zookeeper internally, you can not see the zookeeper process with jps command then you can check its port with 'netstat -nt | grep ZK_PORT' and normally it uses 2181.

```sh
netstat -nt | grep 2181
```

## 2. Check the zookeeper node

If you run zookeeper cluster independently, you can check the node "/hbase/hbaseid" with the zookeeper CLI like this.

```sh
ZOOKEEPER/bin/zkCli.sh
[zk: ...] ls /
[zk: ...] get /hbase/hbaseid
```

Comment: how can I run zookeeper clusters in my system? I don't how to create and run? Will anyone can tell me how to create and run zookeeper cluster?

Comment: can anyone help me to install and run apache atlas? But don't give suggestion as follow apache documentation "already i did i'm facing above issue"? for my linux system.

Comment: I'm not using zookeeper independently, that too I'm using embedded HBase and Solr. Do we have to use zookeeper independently if we have to?then how can i configure that in the atlas (application.properties)

Comment: @Chandraprakash You don't need to have it but there are many applications that need Zookeeper such as HBase, Kafka, Solr and etc.. I recommend you to have a zookeeper cluster. The official site does not recommend to use the embedded HBase and Solr package in production.

Comment: Thank you. So how can I config fullfledged atlas in my machine without embedded HBase and solr. Can you help to figure it out this? By the way we want to use Kafka for Lineage.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help you.

## install atlas

you can download the source code of atlas v2.0.0 or master branch from [here](https://github.com/apache/atlas) and build it.

```sh
$ export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
$ mvn clean install
$ mvn clean package -Pdist
```

If you build the master branch, you can find the server package from /SOURCE_CODE/distro/target/apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-server/apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

You should configure the server prior to run it.
Here are the minimum settings. Please find the atlas-application.properties file in conf directory.

```
atlas.graph.storage.hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx => zookeeper addr and port for hbase
atlas.graph.index.search.backend=[solr or elasticsearch] => choose one you want to use.
atlas.graph.index.hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx => solr or elasticsearch server's addr
atlas.kafka.zookeeper.connect=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx => zookeeper addr and port for Kafka
atlas.kafka.bootstrap.servers=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx => kafka addr
atlas.audit.hbase.zookeeper.quorum=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx => zookeeper addr and port for hbase
```

To run the server,

```sh
$ bin/atlas_start.py
```

## install zookeeper

Actually, to install zookeeper, there is almost nothing to do.
just follow the [steps](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperStarted.html)
In this case, you should change your hbase env. in hbase-env.sh

```sh
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
```

If you see some warnings from hbase log file like 'Could not start ZK at requested port of 2181.' then please check the hbase-site.xml file and set hbase.cluster.distributed to true.

Comment: I have the same problem as @chandra-prakash explains, I have run zookeeper using docker separately, but it still doesn't work. I have tested it using `telnet localhost 2181` and everything was OK, but get an error. Would you mind explain how to run the zookeeper completely?